# SQLite database saves String as "0"

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've just learned how to use SQLite database in Android. And i have one error which i cant figure out.

When i try to save string in my sqlite database, it saves it always as "0", no matter which string i use as an input. This is my code example.

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Log.i("CrimeLab", "put : "+crime.getId().toString());
    values.put(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.UUID, "31b0a98a-4089-46de-8325-4ec673bbd713"); // crime.getId().toString()
    Log.i("CrimeLab", "take: "+values.getAsString(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.UUID));
    values.put(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE, crime.getTitle());
    values.put(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.DATE, crime.getDate().getTime());
    values.put(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.UUID, crime.isSolved() ? 1 : 0);
```

I have class Crime which have it's unique UUID, title, date and if crime is solved. Everything is saved perfectly but only UUID.toString() is saved in database as "0". No matter which string i try to put it will be saved as "0" in my database, here's the picture.

[image]

Here is how it is displayed in the database, everything is good except this string. I have one book, from where i follow my lectures, and it is the same code from the book and it doesn't work. This is how i get my value back from the database.

```
public class CrimeCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper
{
public CrimeCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor)
{
    super(cursor);
}

public Crime getCrime(){

    String uuidString = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.UUID));
    String title = getString(getColumnIndex(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.TITLE));
    long date = getLong(getColumnIndex(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.DATE));
    int isSolved = getInt(getColumnIndex(CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.SOLVED));
// And so on.
```

Answer (score 4):

> Everything is saved perfectly but only UUID.toString() is saved in database as "0".

That is because you have not solved any crimes, and you probably have a typo in your code.

In your code snippet, you are setting `CrimeDbSchema.CrimeTable.Cols.UUID` *twice*. Once it is the UUID. Once it is 0 or 1 depending on `isSolved()`.

I would assume that the second occurrence needs a different column name.

Comment: Just figured it out. After 4 hours of searching and debugging ! What a mistake...